# Sqlite3 & python: Operational error: no such table when table exists

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm writing a database for a site and having trouble accessing the database when a user tries to log in or sign up. I'm able to access the database via putty and can see that the database, table and data do exist.

This is the section that is giving me an error: (sqlite3 is imported)

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home2/slermanr/public_html/cgi-bin/users.db')
cnt = conn.cursor()

for row in cnt.execute('select user_name from users'):

    if int(c["session"].value) == int(row[3]):
        uN = row[0]
if uN == form['user_name'].value:
    try:
        with conn:
            cnt.execute(('UPDATE users SET logged_in = ? WHERE user_name = ?'), (1, uN))
        conn.commit()
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        pass
```

To be slightly more specific this is the error:

LINE 40:         for row in cnt.execute('select user_name from users')

```
<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'>: no such table: users
      args = ('no such table: users',)
      message = 'no such table: users'
```

Any help you can give would be great!

Comment: sqlite3 will do this if the file doesn't exist. Can you just 'open' the file and see what happens then? (i.e. open('/home2/slermanr...'))

Comment: If i open the file via putty, it exists however, it is showing up as a 0 byte file on the server's file system. What would cause that? It seems like that is where my issue is coming from.

Comment: Well, i've solved my own problem but I have no idea why this worked. Simply deleting my database and remaking it fixed the issue.

Comment: In future, you might want to use the sqlite command line client to verify that you can query the database normally (sorry, I thought you'd already done this, which is why I suggested double-checking the path).

Comment: (PS Can I suggest that your select statement be changed so that you only find the user you're interested in? Or even just try to do the UPDATE and find out if anything changed. SELECT then UPDATE is fraught with potential lost update problems...)